# How to count the sum of values of a column in a table output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is the output of a code run, and i would like to know how am i able to count the sum of values of the column 'age' in this table output

|  | value | age | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car | 110 | 10 | 1 |
| Drum | 46 | 3 | 0 |
| Bottle | 12 | 510 | 1 |
| Shoes | 80 | 29 | 1 |

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

`df['age'].sum()` (considering that the table is called `df`)

Comment: will be getting KeyError: 'age'

Comment: This error means that the column name is not `age` but something else... Maybe it's `age `? (With a space after)... Try `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')` first to remove any space that might exist in the column names and then retry the function I proposed in the answer.